# How do you compare two arrays of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string

If i had two `String` arrays, How would I compare each word in `array1` to `array2` to see which is larger?

```
String[] a1 = {"star", "pie", "jelly bean", "car"};
STring[] a2 = {"cookie", "fig", "banana", "soda"};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

comparing arrays:

```
if(a1.length > a2.length)
    return a1
else
    return a2
```

comparing i-th strings:

```
int[] x = new int[a1.length]
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a1[i].length > a2[i].length)
        x[i] = 1
    else
        x[i] = 2
}
```

if in x array is 1 then the string from first array is bigger (larger) else from second

Comment: `a1[i].length`? Are you forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] a1 = {"star", "pie", "jelly bean", "car"};
String[] a2 = {"cookie", "fig", "banana", "soda"};
String [] array;
if(a1.length > a2.length)
    array=a1;
else
    array=a2;
```